# Hibernate: использование StaticMetamodel

Tags: java, hibernate

Установка и настройка.

Добавил зависимость (система сборки - Gradle):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen
compile group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '6.0.0.Alpha2'
```

Указал препроцессор аннотаций:

```
annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.0.0.Alpha2')
```

Используемый в примере ниже класс:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "incrementor")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Author() { }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Сгенерированный класс:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Author.class)
public abstract class Author_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Author, String> firstName;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Author, String> lastName;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Author, Long> id;

    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    public static final String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
    public static final String ID = "id";
}
```

Пример:

```
@Override
public List<Author> findAllByLastName(String lastName) {
    var cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    var query = cb.createQuery(Author.class);
    var author = query.from(Author.class);
    query.where(cb.equal(author.get(Author_.lastName), lastName));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Вызов `author.get(Author_.lastName)` генерирует исключение `NullPointerException`:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <Y> PathImplementor<Y> get(SingularAttribute<? super T, Y> attribute) {
    return getWrappedPathDetyped().get( attribute );
}
```

, в момент вызова параметр attribute равен null.

Пробовал использовать константу LAST_NAME (из класса Author_) - получаю исключение с описанием:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.spi.SingularPathBasic cannot be cast to
>   class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmExpression
>   (org.hibernate.query.criteria.spi.SingularPathBasic and
>   org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmExpression are in module
>   org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha2 of loader 'app')

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854687/jpa-hibernate-static-metamodel-attributes-not-populated-nullpointerexception

Comment: @Sergey, не уверен, что это чем-то поможет - классы Author и Author_ в моем случае находятся в одном и том же пакете. Или мне нужно было обратить внимание на что-то другое?

Comment: Из вопроса не видно что из одного пакета. Больше ничего предложить не могу.